# RecyclerView in Fragment crashes when navigating to another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've been following examples on the web to create a RecyclerView. The only thing I made different is to put the RecyclerView in a Fragment instead of having it in the MainActivity. The RecyclerView displays nicely with the data. But when I navigate to another Fragment the App crashes with an Exception relating to RecyclerView:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
```

Here is a minimal example to reproduce:

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout)
    }
}
```

main_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="package.RecyclerFragment"
              android:id="@+id/fragment"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

RecyclerFragment:

```
class RecyclerFragment : Fragment() {

    private val data = listOf("Moscow", "Washington")

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_list, container, false)
        view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)?.apply {
            adapter = RecyclerAdapter(data)
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return when (item?.itemId) {
            R.id.navigate -> {
                fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.fragment, HelloFragment())?.commit()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

recycler_list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

RecyclerAdapter:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private val data: List<String>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(val view: CardView): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(root: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val listItem = LayoutInflater.from(root.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, root, false) as CardView
        return ViewHolder(listItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text).text = data[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = data.size
}
```

list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5sp">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/text"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/navigate"
          android:title="Navigate"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

HelloFragment:

```
class HelloFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello, container, false)
    }
}
```

hello:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:text="Hello"
          android:textSize="30sp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Is there something wrong with this implementation? How do you use RecyclerView in a Fragment?

Comment: Is the method in the error `shouldIgnore()` is created by you or it is library method?

Comment: That's a library method. I have no idea what it's doing. It's not documented.

Comment: Please check my answer. It is working fine. Let me know if you're facing any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

Just don't use `RecyclerView` as the parent in `RecyclerFragment` layout. Wrap it in `LinearLayout` like this:

recycler_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Method 2**
In your current implementation you have added `RecyclerFragment` from xml but when you try to replace it with `HelloFragment`, it won't get replaced, instead the new fragment will be added over it or below it.

To implement this properly, you should add `RecyclerFragment` from your activity's `onCreate` method like below and remove it from xml:

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.root,RecyclerFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And when you want to replace fragment on options item click do like this:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigate -> {
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root, HelloFragment(), "Hello")
                .commit()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

This way, your previous fragment will be removed and new one will be added.

Answer (score 2):

@Jeel and @Birju showed you the right way to use fragment, but I still leave my answer in case you want to understand deeper why your implementation doesn't work.

**Reason:**

First, looking into main_layout:

```
<ConstraintLayout>

    <fragment class="package.RecyclerFragment"
              android:id="@+id/fragment"
     ... />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

When `main_layout` is inflated in MainActivity, `<fragment>` element is simply replaced by whatever included inside RecyclerFragment's layout a.k.a `recycler_list` layout.

So `main_layout` will actually become:

```
<ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

If you put these code in onResume() in MainActivity, you can see it clearly:

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val parent = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.constraint) 
        val numChild = parent.childCount
        val childView = parent.getChildAt(0)
        Log.d("Parent", parent.toString())
        Log.d("NumChild", numChild.toString())
        Log.d("ChildView", childView.toString())
        return
    }

    // Log
    D/Parent: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{a6e5545 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07004d app:id/constraint}
    D/NumChild: 1
    D/ChildView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{753849a VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f070060 app:id/fragment}
```

Therefore, when you call this line:

```
fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.fragment, HelloFragment())?.commit()
```

It actually took RecyclerView as the **container** view group and add whatever in HelloFragment's layout **into RecyclerView**

For evidence, you can take a look at these lines in **FragmentManager** class:

```
// mContainerId here is R.id.fragment in your layout

container = (ViewGroup) mContainer.onFindViewById(f.mContainerId);

// Now container is RecyclerView

...

f.performCreateView(f.performGetLayoutInflater(
                                    f.mSavedFragmentState), container, f.mSavedFragmentState)

// After this line, f.mView is the view inside hello.xml

...

container.addView(f.mView);

// Add layout in hello.xml into RecyclerView
```

Because RecyclerView is designed to hold ViewHolders created from data in Adapter, it still keep a variable called **childCount** (= 3 in this case) even after Hello's fragment view is added inside RecyclerView and removed all ViewHolders from it.

When new view added, RecyclerView dispatch new layout, which then call a function named findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions()

```
private void findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(int[] into) {

        final int count = mChildHelper.getChildCount();
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            final ViewHolder holder = getChildViewHolderInt(mChildHelper.getChildAt(i));
            if (holder.shouldIgnore()) {
                continue;
            }
```

As you can see, because all ViewHolders have been removed, `holder will be null` and NPE will be thrown when it comes to line `if (holder.shouldIgnore()) {`

Thank you for reading this long answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you bit of change if you want to change `Fragment`s inside `Activity` dynamically.

1. When you want to change fragments in activity, take a FrameLayout in your layout file *(main_layout)* of `MainActivity` like below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <FrameLayout
               android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
2. Then replace fragments programmatically in `MainActivity`, Initially we load `RecyclerFragment` in to our `fragment_container`.

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           setContentView(R.layout.main_layout)
           supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.fragment_container, RecyclerFragment())

       }
   }
   ```
3. providing `ViewGroup` to `RecyclerFragment` fragment *(Optional but recommended)*:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:id="@+id/list"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

Now, run your project and everything will be working fine.

---

About your crash :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
```

It was `NullPointerException` because when you navigate to next fragment `HelloFragment`, `RecyclerFragment` goes to detached state & object `RecyclerView` was **null** at that instance.

Comment: Actually, RecyclerView was **not null** at that moment. Which is **null** here is the ViewHolder at position 0 inside that RecyclerView.